# MySQL JOIN LEFT query turning up blank

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, left-join

I run the query below to link two tables and get the values in the second table, based on the id or in this case `magacin_sifra`.

```
$query = "SELECT 
    gumi.magacin_sifra, magacin_pp.magacin_kolicina as kolicina_pp, magacin_pp.magacin_cena as cena_pp
    FROM gumi
    LEFT JOIN magacin_pp ON gumi.magacin_sifra = magacin_pp.magacin_sifra       
     ";

$results = $conn->query($query);
if($results->num_rows) {
    while($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
        echo "{$row->magacin_ime} ({$row->kolicina_pp}) = {$row->cena_pp}<br>";
    }
}else {
    echo 'No results!';
}
```

However the output I get is completely blank.

```
() = 
() = 
() = 
() = 
() = 
() = 
() =
```

Am I doing something wrong?

---

`var_dump($results)` = `object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(3) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(7) ["type"]=> int(0) }`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do the results look the same when you run this query in a mysql tool (like phpmyadmin or workbench, etc)?

Comment: You used the wrong `->` field names. do a `var_dump($row)` to see what PHP created. note that since you're selecting fields like `foo.bar`, PHP can NOT create object references `$row->foo.bar`, because that's illegal PHP. It's rewriting the identifiers to something else.

Comment: @MarcB The table name is ignores when creating the property names, so he's doing it right.

Comment: This is the result you'll get if none of the rows in `gumi` have any matching rows in `magacin_pp`.

Comment: ^^ exactly. @Borsn, use `INNER JOIN` instead, if that is the intent

Comment: Doesn't work with `INNER JOIN`. @i--

Comment: @Barmar but they do, the ID's are the same.

Comment: You're joining on `magacin_sifra`, those are the columns that have to match.

Comment: And they do. Both in gumi.magacin_sifra and magacin_pp.magacin_sifra @Barmar

Comment: Post some sample contents of the two tables.

Comment: @Barmar I've added some screen shots from phpMyAdmin.

Comment: What are the datatypes of `magacin_sifra` in the two tables? Why does it have a leading `0` in `gumi`, but not in `magacin_pp`?

Comment: `magacin_sifra` is an integer. Um, its done by a script thats outside of my control...so no clue. Would that be the problem?

Comment: Integers do not start with 0. You can potentially make it work with `INNER JOIN magacin_pp ON CAST(gumi.magacin_sifra as INTEGER) = magacin_pp.magacin_sifra`, but it is not the best solution, and I would not recommend it. Is it Serbian (sifra, kolicina, cena)?

Answer (score -1):

Can you try var_dump for $results and show here?

```
var_dump($results)
```

Comment: `object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(3) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(7) ["type"]=> int(0) }`

Comment: This should be a comment, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: What is `magacin_ime` i dont see this in query

Comment: Thats the name column. @mischief